# How do I pass my own custom arguments to build.ps1?

Tags: c#, cakebuild

I tried build.ps1 -SettingsProfile "Customer", but it outputs

```
More than one build script specified.
```

In my Cake script I fetch via

```
Argument("SettingsProfile", "Default")
```

And if I skip the argument to build.ps1 then it'll work, but obviously becomes "Default".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume you’re using the [default](https://github.com/cake-build/resources/blob/develop/build.ps1) boostrapper.
If so there’s a `-ScriptArgs` parameter you can use to pass your custom Cake arguments.

Cake arguments are not formatted like standard PowerShell parameters (`-Key value`) but as `--Key="value"`
As such your scenario would look like this

```
.\build.ps1 -ScriptArgs '--SettingsProfile="Customer"'
```

Your Cake script argument usage looks fine, so above modification should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks! that sorted it.

Comment: Yes: 
powershell -File build.ps1 -ScriptArgs '--deployEnv=st','--bldversion=1.2.3'

Comment: @JohnKorsnes: Using multiple args your way gives me a 'More than one build script specified'
`powershell -File build.ps1 -ScriptArgs '--deploymentPackagePath=\\server\folder1','--releasePackagePath=\\server\folder2'`

Comment: It is stranger than so since `.\build.ps1 -ScriptArgs '--dir="../CompulsoryCow.Meta/CompulsoryCow.Meta"', '--proj="CompulsoryCow.Meta"' -Target Package` works while adding a third parameter `.\build.ps1 -ScriptArgs '--dir="../CompulsoryCow.Meta/CompulsoryCow.Meta"', '--proj="CompulsoryCow.Meta"', '--version="3.0.2"' -Target Package` results in a `Error: Argument value is not a valid boolean value.`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how far you want to go as well, you also have the option of extending the bootstrapper to accept your input parameter as a PowerShell argument.  There is a tutorial on how you can extend the bootstrapper here:

http://cakebuild.net/docs/tutorials/extending-the-bootstrapper